# AutoPlay audio and play only once using JQuery

Tags: android, jquery, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Below is the sample for audio player:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>audio.js</title>
    <script src="./audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./includes/index.css" media="screen">
    <script>
      audiojs.events.ready(function() {
        audiojs.createAll();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>audio.js</h1>
    </header>

    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>


  </body>
</html>
```

With this, I want to add some constraints like don't want to show the play button.Instead it will automatically play after 10 secs and it can play only once. How can I do with this. If anyone knows solution please help me to get out of this issue. Reference. https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the play/pause button by changing its style of `.play-pause` to `display:none`

Set `autoplay` to `false` to avoid playback at load and use `setTimeout` to play after 10 sec.

Refer below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>audio.js</title>
    <script src="./audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./includes/index.css" media="screen">
    <style>
        .play-pause {
            display: none;
        }

        .scrubber {
            display: none;
        }

        .audiojs {
            width: 110px;
        }

        .audiojs .time {
            border-left: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>audio.js</h1>
    </header>

    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" id="player"></audio>
    <label id="audio_stats"></label>
    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById("player");
        var settings = {
            autoplay: false,
            loop: false,
            preload: true,
            swfLocation: 'audiojs/audiojs.swf',
            trackEnded: function (e) {
                document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Track Ended...";
            }
        }

        audiojs.events.ready(function () {
            var a = audiojs.create(element, settings);
            var count = 11;
            var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

            function timer() {
                count = count - 1;
                if (count <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    a.play();
                    document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Playing...";
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Will Start in " + count + " sec.";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add text above audio like "audio will begin in 10 secs ,9 secs like timer will show" and similarly after completion of audio it will show text as completed.And it can play only once

Comment: In addition user can't forward or backward the audio

Comment: and onemore issue in that..I have 17 audios in single page with mulitple div if I press next button it will second audio and it will pause first audio if I try to comeback it willnot play audio1 similarly it will work for all audio

Comment: And need to add small constraint while playing audio user can't forward or backward

Comment: can u help me for this issue.

Comment: @KavyaShree What is it that you need?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268225/control-multiple-audio-access-with-single-page-using-jquery this is the question where I explained detaily

Comment: Do you know solution for this issue.

Comment: I try to pause audio with the element ID but what is happening .It willnot pause before play right..While buffer I can't stop can u tell that alone atleast

Comment: Or else will add very small constraint till audio start playing user cannot choose any previous and next button

Comment: @KavyaShree Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42295756/3802503