# Control Multiple Audio Access in Single Page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, audiojs

Hiii Everyone,

This is the sample code for my audio play.It will buffer and start play in 10 secs after that it willnot play again the same audio this the scenario I tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>audio.js</title>
        <script src="./audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./includes/index.css" media="screen">
        <style>
            .play-pause {
                display: none;
            }
           .audiojs {
                width: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>audio.js</h1>
        </header>

        <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" id="player"></audio>
        <label id="audio_stats"></label>
        <script>
            var element = document.getElementById("player");
            var settings = {
                autoplay: false,
                loop: false,
                preload: true,
                swfLocation: 'audiojs/audiojs.swf',
                trackEnded: function (e) {
                    document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Completed...";
                }
            }

            audiojs.events.ready(function () {
                var a = audiojs.create(element, settings);
                var count = 11;
                var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

                function timer() {
                    count = count - 1;
                    if (count <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(counter);
                        a.play();
                        document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Playing...";
                        return;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Will Start in " + count + " sec.";
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is the reference https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ In my site I have nearly 17 audio. Each div enclose with single audio. first div is having audio with id "player(means 1st audio)" similarly in 2nd div "player1(means 2nd audio)" audio will be there.for first div I will have one button with "next question" similarly for all 17 divs there will be previous and next button.What is the issue is all 17 audios are buffered and played simultaneously Instead "player(means 1st audio)" will start buffer once the page opened.And when I click next button second audio should start buffer.And if I press previous button "player(means 1st audio)" should not be play again because only one time It should play.Similarly it will work for all audio.If anybody give me solution for this Issue.It will be more helpful.Im struggling in this issue longtime.Please help me anyone.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below code it is as per your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>audio.js</title>
    <script src="./audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./includes/index.css" media="screen">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .play-pause {
            display: none;
        }

        .scrubber {
            display: none;
        }

        .audiojs {
            width: 110px;
        }

        .audiojs .time {
            border-left: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>audio.js</h1>
    </header>

    <audio src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/juicy.mp3" id="player"></audio>
    <label id="audio_stats"></label>
    <br/>
    <button id="next" disabled>Next</button>

    <ol style="display:none;">
        <li class=""><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/02-juicy-r.mp3">juicy-r</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/03-its-all-about-the-crystalizabeths.mp3">it's all about the crystalizabeths</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/04-islands-is-the-limit.mp3">islands is the limit</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/05-one-more-chance-for-a-heart-to-skip-a-beat.mp3">one more chance for a heart to skip a beat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/06-suicidal-fantasy.mp3">suicidal fantasy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/07-everyday-shelter.mp3">everyday shelter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/08-basic-hypnosis.mp3">basic hypnosis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/09-infinite-victory.mp3">infinite victory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/10-the-curious-incident-of-big-poppa-in-the-nighttime.mp3">the curious incident of big poppa in the nighttime</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-src="http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/mp3/11-mo-stars-mo-problems.mp3">mo stars mo problems</a></li>
    </ol>

    <script>
        var element = document.getElementById("player");
        var settings = {
            autoplay: false,
            loop: false,
            preload: true,
            swfLocation: 'audiojs/audiojs.swf',
            trackEnded: function(e) {
                document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Track Ended...";
                var next = $('ol li.playing').next();
                if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
                next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
                audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
                audio.play();
            }
        }

        audiojs.events.ready(function() {
            var a = audiojs.createAll(settings);
            var count = 11;
            var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

            function timer() {
                count = count - 1;
                if (count <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    audio.play();
                    document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Playing..." + audio.mp3;
                    $('#next').removeAttr('disabled');
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Will Start in " + count + " sec.";
            }

            // Load in the first track
            var audio = a[0];
            first = $('ol a').attr('data-src');
            $('ol li').first().addClass('playing');
            audio.load(first);

            // Load in a track on click
            $('ol li').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
                audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
                audio.play();
            });
            // Keyboard shortcuts
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
                // right arrow
                if (unicode == 39) {
                    var next = $('li.playing').next();
                    if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
                    next.click();
                    // back arrow
                } else if (unicode == 37) {
                    //var prev = $('li.playing').prev();
                    //if (!prev.length) prev = $('ol li').last();
                    //prev.click();
                    // spacebar
                } else if (unicode == 32) {
                    //audio.playPause();
                }
            });

            $("#next").click(function() {
                var next = $('li.playing').next();
                if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
                next.click();
                document.getElementById("audio_stats").innerText = "Playing..." + audio.mp3;
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually I tried this with different way. what I did is I will call player1 element once click on next button similarly I will pause element of audio already playing now.What I want to know is we have one timer right 10,9,8 secs while that it willnot allow to click next or previous button Is this possible

Comment: Exactly.. Thank u so much

Comment: Kindly check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295781/auto-record-and-allow-to-play-once-using-jquery .. Similarly I want to record already we done for audio play now I want same with record

Comment: Can u help me for this issue?

Comment: Give me some time, will look through it.

Comment: Actually I have to submit these things at 12'o clock today.Thats why Im askng u please help me as soon as possble